# Preview displays as expected, but actual post cuts text out

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, markdown, markdown-preview

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921921/a-read-only-checkbox-in-c-wpf/922141#922141) answer, the second code block cuts off half way through.

If you click to edit the answer, the full code block (and a third one) is there, and displays fully as expected in preview pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better? There was a truncation issue a while ago, where the pre-generated html is truncated (but the underlying markdown isn't). I just used edit/save to fix.

Comment: was this actually truncated, though? looks unchanged to me.

Comment: @Jeff - yes, it was appearing truncated. It was cut off in the middle of one of the elements `<Set`, IIRC, was the last of the code block. The post continued underneath, which is even odder.

Comment: Yup, that's appearing correctly now. I know what to do if I see it again.